# how to redirect a form based on radio button selection?

Tags: html, wordpress

I am trying to code a snippet, that redirects the user based on their contact form 7 radio button selection. The redirection works, however, sometimes the redirection is to the wrong link.

The radio button part of the contact form (sorry the German labels):

```html
<div class="single-row">
    <b> Ich komme… </b>
        <div class="single-row">
        <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap" data-name="radio-899">
        <span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-radio" id="menuradio">
            <span class="wpcf7-list-item first">
                <input type="radio" name="radio-899" value="... nur zur Party.">
                <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">… nur zur Party.</span>
            </span>
            <span class="wpcf7-list-item">
                <input type="radio" name="radio-899" value="... zum Abendessen &amp; Party.">
                <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">… zum Abendessen &amp; Party.</span>
            </span>
            <span class="wpcf7-list-item last">
                <input type="radio" name="radio-899" value="... leider nicht.">
                <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">… leider nicht.</span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

The code snippet which I have added to the footer:

```html
const redirect = () => {
   window.open('https://www.paypal.com/paypalme/.../25,'_blank'); 
};

const input = document.querySelector('body #menuradio input[name="radio-899"][value="... nur zur Party."]');
if(input){
  input.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
    if(event.target.value){
      document.addEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', redirect);
    } else {
      document.removeEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', redirect);
    }
  })
}
    
const redirect1 = () => {
    window.open('https://www.paypal.com/paypalme/... /30','_blank');
};

const input1 = document.querySelector('body #menuradio input[name="radio-899"][value="... zum Abendessen & Party."]');
if(input1){
  input1.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
    if(event.target.value){
      document.addEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', redirect1);
    } else {
      document.removeEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', redirect1);
    }
  })
}
    
const inputNotGoing = document.querySelector('body #menuradio input[name="radio-899"][value="... leider nicht."]');
    if (inputNotGoing) {
      inputNotGoing.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
        if (event.target.checked) {
          document.removeEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', redirect);
          document.removeEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', redirect1);
        }
      })
    }
```

How can I make sure the redirection is to the right link. I would be very happy for any help!!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the button, by binding the Onchange attribute, you can use the following features in case of replacement or any change on the radio button.

```
let formEvents = {
  paypal: function() {
    console.log('redirecting');
    //uncomment the following line when you use it in your script
    //window.location.assign("http://www.paypal.com");
  },
  money: function() {
    $('.div2').show('slow', function() {
      setTimeout("$('.div2').fadeOut(4000)", 500);
    });
  },
  mastercard: function() {
    $('.div1').show('slow', function() {
      $('.div1').fadeOut(4000);
    });
  }
}

$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var value = $(this).find('input:radio:checked').val();

  if (formEvents.hasOwnProperty(value)) {
    formEvents[value].call(this);
  }

});
```

```
.div1,
.div2 {
  display: none;
  background: #c8c8c8;
  border: 2px dashed #000;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="radio">
    <label><input type="radio" name="selection" value="paypal">paypal</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <label><input type="radio" name="selection" value="money">money</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <label><input type="radio" name="selection" value="mastercard">mastercard</label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" id="button1" name="button">Check</button>
</form>


<div class="div1">div 1</div>
<div class="div2">div 2</div>
```